# Is there something like "Mac OS X manager" to control all Macs in one network?

Tags: macos

It's needed to control from a Mac (turn off, install software, etc.), all another Macs connected to the same network (in the same classroom). Is there a software for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Remote Desktop http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/ might be what you are looking for.

Comment: It's not free. Is there free alternatives?